# CORS - Lumen and Angular request

Tags: angular, cors, lumen

I have an Angular app running at http://localhost:4200 and a Lumen API running at http://localhost:8000.

I'm using barryvdh/laravel-cors and all my POSTS requests returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Any clues about that? My Angular Database Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  get(url: string) {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/" + url)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }

  post(url: string, data) {
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/"+ url, data)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }

}
```

All GET requests work properly.

Comment: Did, u solve this issue? cus I ran in to the same.

Comment: @Shivam In localhost I just used a Chrome extension called CORS, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling apache mod_headers will fix this issue.
Run below commands

1. a2enmod headers
2. sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you pass and how you handle in the back-end. did you try stringifying data

```
JSON.stringify(data)

post(url: string, data) {
return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/"+ url, JSON.stringify(data))
  .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access to your Angular server on Lumen

If you are not using CORS Just add this line on /bootstrap/app.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200/');
```

or for everyone:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

If you are using CORS you must set the same thing on the headers on App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware (or whatever is called your CORS file)

```
$headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];
```

Comment: I'm trying this and it is not working.. I've tested to see if the middleware is being called (`die()` is being called).. GET requests are fine but POST/PUT just seems to fall over.

`$headers = [
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
   'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
  ];
`

Comment: Ignore me... wrong URL in Angular app. Was setup to go to a GET URL.. **face palm**